How to run tests concurrently but execute classes within each test sequentially using TestNG XML configuration?
I want to configure my TestNG XML file to achieve concurrent execution of tests while ensuring that the classes within each test run sequentially. Currently, I have set the parallel attribute to true for the suite, enabling concurrent execution of tests. However, I have set the parallel attribute to false for each individual test to ensure sequential execution of classes within each test.
`   

<test name="Panel Tests - Part 1" parallel="false" thread-count="1">
    <!-- Test configurations -->
</test>

<test name="Panel Tests - Part 2" parallel="false" thread-count="1">
    <!-- Test configurations -->
</test>

<!-- Other tests -->


`
Despite this configuration, the tests are not running concurrently. Could someone please advise on how to correctly configure TestNG to achieve concurrent execution of tests while ensuring sequential execution of classes within each test?

Have you tried setting parallel="tests" for the suite?
With this config all methods from the specified test classes will be executed sequentially, while test groups themselves will be executed in separate threads.
If you also want to run test methods from test classes in the order they are defined in the class, see the priority attribute of the @Test annotation. (If I'm not mistaken, by default methods are executed in alphabetical order)
